# Attach pipeline artifact to release in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In my repo only source files are checked in — the code is tested and the dist files are generated in a pipeline. I then want to be able to tag a specific version and attach the artifacts generated by this pipeline to it. Ideally this should all happen with as little manual intervention as possible.

What is the best way to reference pipeline artifacts from a release?

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `release-cli` in a stage after the job you built your app, to upload to a release a file form a previous job you'll need that build job id that you can store in a file in the artifacts:

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Build your app"
    - echo "${CI_JOB_ID}" > CI_JOB_ID.txt # This way you know the job id in the next stage
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - your_app.exe
      - CI_JOB_ID.txt
    expire_in: never
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG


release:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  script:
    - |
      release-cli create --name "Release $CI_COMMIT_TAG" --tag-name $CI_COMMIT_TAG \
        --assets-link "{\"name\":\"Executable file\",\"url\":\"https://gitlab.com/some/repo/-/jobs/`cat CI_JOB_ID.txt`/artifacts/file/your_app.exe\"}"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

This way every time you `tag` your repo, it will create a release if the pipeline succeed.

Comment: When I run this I get an error stating `cat: can't open 'CI_JOB_ID.txt': No such file or directory` I guess it can't access the file.  Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: @reddisht I know it's a bit late to the party, but my guess would be it's because the jobs may run out of order. Add `needs: ["build"]` to the release job to ensure they execute in the proper order